# Replace the behavior of an hash link anchor with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following bit of code :

```
                <a href="#anch">Anchor hash link</a>
                <div id="anch">
                  <ul>
                    <li>foo</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
```

I can't use anchor hash link for several different redirecting reasons.
Is there a way to emulate its behavior with a small jquery script ? (to get rid of the href, and instead having an onClick doing exactly the same ?)

Comment: It sounds like you're doing it wrong. The "redirecting reasons" argument means that you hijack the original purpose of hash links, perhaps there's a way to opt out of those redirection hooks for certain elements?

Answer (score 1):

To replace the behaviour with jQuery without adding a # to the url:

```
$('a[href*="#"]').click(function(e) {
  var scrollAnchor = $(this).attr('href');
  $('html, body').scrollTop($(scrollAnchor).offset().top);
  return false;
});
```

See this bin: https://jsbin.com/tizixapabu/edit?html,js,output

Links still work as usual.